# How can I extract the feature vector of the last hidden layer of the Alex net in pytorch?

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

I’ve trained an Alex net in pytorch and I want to extract feature vectors from the layers
What is the function which I should use?

Comment: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-extract-features-of-an-image-from-a-trained-model/119/11

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you can define a function in the model class which takes input and output the features you like, for example:

```
class model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        # init codes
    def forward(self, input):
        # forward codes
    def yourfunc(self, input):
        # codes
        #return feature1, feature2
```

This **yourfunc** only takes your input and outputs features you need, it does no backward computation. You just need to call it wherever you need. And I don't think there are built-in functions in PyTorch can do that since it is easy to implement by yourself.